# How to get dynamically-generated JSON into PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've got a JSON value that has been converted from a JavaScript object using JSON.stringify. I'm trying to parse the contents of the JSON using PHP, but I haven't had any luck. I'm sure I'm doing something really basic wrong.

In file1.php, I've got something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/json2.js'></script>
    <script>
        var irxmlnewsreleases = new Array();
        irxmlnewsreleases[0]={
            "attachmentfileid":12039
         };
         var news_release = JSON.stringify(irxmlnewsreleases);
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#response").text(news_release);  
         });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="response"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm then trying to read this data from `file1.php` using `json_decode` in file2.php.

I tried first (wrongly) using `file_get_contents` and have been bashing at this for a while without success. I guess the issue is obviously that the JSON value doesn't exist until the JavaScript is run, so PHP is of course never able to read the value of the jQuery-generated div content. What I don't know is how to get that value.

The JSON is being generated successfully in file1.php and is valid JSON (I've run it through jsonlint).

What's a better way of getting the value of that dynamically-generated JSON into PHP?

Comment: Do an AJAX call to some script to send the data to php if you want. I'll post a full answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#response").text(news_release);  
         $.post('file2.php', { php_post_var1: news_release }, function (data) { 
           //do something with the PHP script output here if you want
         });
     });
```

Then in your PHP script `file2.php` do something like

```
<?php
$news_release = $_POST['php_post_var1'];
echo 'PHP received ' . $news_release;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Milo, thanks for responding. I've tried that approach and am getting a blank value for `$news_release`.

Comment: I wonder if it might have to do with the authentication on my web server (it's set to password-protect the directory with an Apache directive). I'll check that now.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be it. Still not getting a value when printing the value of `$_POST`.

Comment: You should still be able to do an ajax call in an apache password protected access directory.  I'd go with news_release probably doesn't have any data in your javascript. try setting it to an explicit string to rule out the ajax.  and in your `function(data) { console.log(data); }` is very useful in debugging situations like these.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for replying back - very useful! The problem was that I was trying to echo out the PHP variable by loading the file directly in the browser. The return value from the callback in the `$.post` function showed me that I was indeed getting what I needed.

Comment: If you want to access it from the browser, `$_GET` is useful `http://yourdomain/script2.php?news_release=Man bites Dog` and use `$.get` in your jquery which has the same paramaters as `$.post`